# Python combine CSVs, remove header and remove blanks

Tags: python, csv, glob, shutil

**I’m extremely new to Python & trying to figure the below out:**

I have multiple *CSV files* (monthly files) that I’m trying to combine into a yearly file. The monthly files all have headers, so I’m trying to keep the first header & remove the rest. I used the below script which accomplished this, however there are *10 blank rows* between each month.

Does anyone know what I can add to this to remove the blank rows?

```
import shutil
import glob


#import csv files from folder
path = r'data/US/market/merged_data'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
allFiles.sort()  # glob lacks reliable ordering, so impose your own if output order matters
with open('someoutputfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline()  # Throw away header on all but first file
            # Block copy rest of file from input to output without parsing
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the dataset isn't bigger than you memory, I suggest reading each file in pandas, concatenating the dataframes and filtering from there.  blank rows will probably show up as nan.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'data/US/market/merged_data'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
allFiles.sort()
df = pd.Dataframe()
for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
    #append data to existing dataframe
    df = df.append(pd.read(fname), ignore_index = True)
#hopefully, this will drop blank rows
df = df.dropna(how = 'all')
#write to file
df.to_csv('someoutputfile.csv')
```